# Hide yaxis with legend

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to hide the yaxis and the series with klick on a series in the legend?

```
legend: {
    align: "right",
    layout: "vertical",
    enabled: true,
    verticalAlign: "middle"
},
```

cheers

Comment: Defaulty when you hide serie, yAxis disappears: http://jsfiddle.net/4VnaV/

Comment: but not the label - like in your example, "values" is still there

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [showEmpty](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.showEmpty) as false.